# C# regex matches finding nearly identical strings

Tags: c#, regex, duplicates

I'm running some regex to sort through a text document and i'm running into a problem with regex. For example there are two pieces of text i'm capturing : `acb` and `oacb`. My pattern will find both of them, however `oacb` will be seen as `acb`resulting in a wrong amount of times matched. Is there any fix for this?
My regex is,

```
\b:\s*\d{1,5}\*{0,1}\s*-\s*\d{1,5}\*{0,1}
```

Comment: `My pattern will find both of them, ` yet you want to ignore one of them?

Comment: The actual string it looks for will have digits, sometimes a * and a - as well. 
An example of both full strings would be... Acb: 2125 - 2325 and
Oacb: 12375 - 12850

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I wasn't aware c# had a \b operator. It now finds the correct values. Thanks!